# How do I get the inverse laplace transform of $(s+2)*e^{-s}/(s+1)^2$

Tags: laplace-transform

There is no way to break apart this fraction I think, and I don't see a property on a Laplace transform table. How would I go about this?

Comment: The result is $e^{(1 - t)}~t~\Theta(-1 + t)$, which can be obtained by breaking the expression on two terms and looking up no tables the corresponding inverse transforms. Of course, $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** write
$$\frac{(s+1+1)e^{-s}}{(s+1)^2}=\frac{e^{-s}}{s+1}+\frac{e^{-s}}{(s+1)^2}$$
and use
$${\cal L}(e^{ct})=\frac{1}{s-c}$$
$${\cal L}(t^ne^{ct})=\frac{n!}{(s-c)^{n+1}}$$
$${\cal L}\Big(H_c(t)f(t-c)\Big)=e^{cs}{\cal L}(f)$$
where $H(t)$ is Heaviside function.